# How do I formulate offset function for nth column in different sheet

Tags: excel, offset

I've been struggling with this all day, though I'm sure it's not impossible.

I have a sheet with a value in every 3rd column and I need to copy this value into another sheet, ignoring the 1st and 2nd column.

So for: `A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1` in sheet 1

I just need `C1` , `F1` in sheet 2

Is there a formula that I can drag across all columns? This has to happen for rows 1 - 150 as well.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

`=OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,COLUMN()*2,1,1)`

Modify the sheet name as necessary.

Use the argument `Column()*2` for the column offset. This takes the integer value of the current column number, and multiplies it by 2. So the offset for column A is 2, which refers to column C, the offset for column B is 4, which refers to column F, etc.

Comment: Great! If it's worked for you, please consider marking the answer as "accepted" so that others may know this question is resolved.  Cheers!